# Animation between two Activities does not work

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to do a slide animation between two Activities when then one starts the other,

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(TestAppActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    TestAppActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter,   R.anim.animation_leave);
    finish();
}
```

There is no animation at all. The xmls are, for enter:

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="3000" />
```

And for leave:

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="3000" />
```

I can see what is gong wrong here. Using Android 2.3.3. Thanks.

Comment: Is this activity inside an ActivityGroup?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter, R.anim.animation_leave);` after `finish();`.

Comment: Neither of your animations seem to have interpolators.  Put something like `android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"` in your `set` tag and see if it works then.

Comment: Those were the only things that looked odd to me.  Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @user987639 After looking through some of my projects, I've noticed that all the tween animations that use percentages have a "p" after the percent sign to tell Android that it's a percentage.  I suppose it couldn't hurt to try that.

Comment: Thanks for ypur help. Tried that, too. No change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212610/how-do-i-make-a-swipe-animation-from-left-to-right-transition-between-activities/13224118#13224118 this answer should solve your problem

Comment: @DeeV, actually `%p`, as stated by the official documentation, indicates `"a percentage relative to its parent"`. [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#translate-element]

Answer (score 0):

To do an animation where the first activity go to the left and the second activity enters from the right :

`slide_out_left.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
 Animation : Perform animation : Out - Direction : Left
-->

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
       android:duration="400"
       android:fromXDelta="0"
       android:toXDelta="-100%p" />

</set>
```

`slide_in_right.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
 Animation : Perform animation : In - Direction : Right
-->

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

*Note* : you can change `android:duration` if you want.

And you have to add this code :

```
public void onClick(View view) {

   Intent intent = new Intent(TestAppActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
   finish();
}
```