# left slide in and right slide in animation not working in samsung s2 android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-animation

I have implemented animation from moving one activity to another activity but it is not working in  samsung s2 in android 2.3.3.Can anybody tell wat is problem

```
Intent secondIntent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(secondIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Thanks

Comment: are you testing this on emulator or device?

Comment: @QadirHussain am testing in device

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712665/animation-between-two-activities-does-not-work

Comment: @mohan make sure animation is not disabled from your device setting.

Comment: see this http://www.howtogeek.com/175033/how-to-speed-up-any-android-phone-by-disabling-animations/ and http://pocketnow.com/android/how-to-disable-screen-animations-in-android-40-ics

Comment: @QadirHussain can you tell how to enable animation in device